# What is the most efficent way to use Eloquent to generate a time series data?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**Background**

So I have the goal of creating a chart below. Right now, it's filled up with dummy data, but you get the point. The frontend [library](https://frappe.io/charts/docs) I am using does not support date-time multivariate time series, but I really love its simplicity, so instead of changing the charting library, I decided to generate the data in the structure it needs.

[image]

```
const data = {
                labels: [
                    "2020-12-16",
                    "2020-12-17",
                    "2020-12-18",
                    "2020-12-19",
                ],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        name: "Confirmed", chartType: "bar",
                        values: [25, 40, 30, 35]
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Canceled", chartType: "bar",
                        values: [5, 10, 1, 8]
                    },
                    {
                        name: "No Show", chartType: "bar",
                        values: [1, null, 7, 4]
                    }
                ]
            }
```

**Eloquent**

I am using the following query on Eloquent that does what I want, almost, but there's caveats.

```
Booking
::whereSalonId({salonId})
->select('booking_status','created_at')->get()
->groupBy('booking_status')
```

It gives me something like this below:

```
[!] Aliasing 'Booking' to 'App\Models\Booking' for this Tinker session.
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2284
     all: [
       "confirmed" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2228
         all: [
           App\Models\Booking {#2328
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-11-16 13:11:31",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2330
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-11-16 13:22:05",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2332
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-11-17 04:59:15",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2333
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-11-17 06:30:13",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2334
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-11-17 06:38:02",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2335
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-11-17 06:54:07",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2336
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-11-17 06:59:25",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2337
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-11-17 07:02:57",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2338
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-11-17 07:03:54",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2339
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-11-17 07:15:57",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2340
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-11-17 07:17:08",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2341
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-11-17 07:18:07",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2342
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-11-17 07:20:26",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2343
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-11-17 08:38:33",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2344
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-05 16:36:28",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2345
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-06 04:37:48",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2346
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-06 04:40:39",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2347
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-06 04:45:06",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2348
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-06 04:49:17",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2349
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-06 04:50:18",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2350
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-06 04:51:38",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2351
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-06 05:06:14",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2352
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-06 05:23:10",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2353
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-06 05:31:41",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2354
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-06 05:37:50",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2355
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-06 05:40:17",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2356
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-06 05:47:06",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2357
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-06 05:52:36",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2358
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-06 05:54:21",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2359
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-06 06:12:18",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2360
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-06 06:18:07",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2361
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-07 05:14:47",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2362
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-07 05:55:49",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2363
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-07 05:58:59",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2364
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-14 20:45:09",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2366
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-16 19:52:34",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2367
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-17 20:44:26",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2368
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-18 07:28:47",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2369
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-18 23:28:34",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2373
             booking_status: "confirmed",
             created_at: "2020-12-19 03:47:51",
           },
         ],
       },
       "canceled" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2235
         all: [
           App\Models\Booking {#2331
             booking_status: "canceled",
             created_at: "2020-11-17 03:22:40",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2370
             booking_status: "canceled",
             created_at: "2020-12-18 23:30:28",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2371
             booking_status: "canceled",
             created_at: "2020-12-18 23:32:52",
           },
           App\Models\Booking {#2372
             booking_status: "canceled",
             created_at: "2020-12-19 03:39:43",
           },
         ],
       },
       "no_show" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2285
         all: [
           App\Models\Booking {#2365
             booking_status: "no_show",
             created_at: "2020-12-14 21:36:30",
           },
         ],
       },
     ],
   }
```

**The Problem**

- It really doesn't look like the series that my charting library expects.
- I am not sure how to add `null` to cases where there's no datapoint for a group.
- For example, if there's no 'cancel' on a date, I would like a `null` or `0` rather than skip.

I am not sure if there is any decent and efficient way of doing this in Eloquent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Attempt**

I got something working but I don't really like the way it is. Not clean, maybe inefficient.

```
// Set the date range
$from = date('2020-11-16');
$to = date('2020-12-16');


// Order bookings to get group daily counts
$bookings = Booking::whereSalonId({salonId})->get();
$groups = $bookings
->whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])
->groupBy(['booking_status', function ($item) { 
    return \Carbon\Carbon
            ::parse($item['created_at'])
            ->format('Y-m-d');
}])
->map(function ($dateGroup) { 
    return $dateGroup
            ->map
            ->count();
})
->toArray();

// Generate intended date ranges
$ranges = \Carbon\CarbonPeriod::create($from, '1 day', $to);

// Final result goes here
$result = array();

// Go over each group in earlier segmentation
foreach ($groups as $groupName => $groupResult) {

    // Attempt to hunt the count
    foreach ($ranges as $range) {
        $date =  \Carbon\Carbon::parse($range)->format('Y-m-d');
        $result[$groupName][$date] = $groupResult[$date] ?? null;
    }
}

$result;
```

**Results**

```
[!] Aliasing 'Booking' to 'App\Models\Booking' for this Tinker session.
=> [
     "confirmed" => [
       "2020-11-16" => 2,
       "2020-11-17" => 12,
       "2020-11-18" => null,
       "2020-11-19" => null,
       "2020-11-20" => null,
       "2020-11-21" => null,
       "2020-11-22" => null,
       "2020-11-23" => null,
       "2020-11-24" => null,
       "2020-11-25" => null,
       "2020-11-26" => null,
       "2020-11-27" => null,
       "2020-11-28" => null,
       "2020-11-29" => null,
       "2020-11-30" => null,
       "2020-12-01" => null,
       "2020-12-02" => null,
       "2020-12-03" => null,
       "2020-12-04" => null,
       "2020-12-05" => 1,
       "2020-12-06" => 16,
       "2020-12-07" => 3,
       "2020-12-08" => null,
       "2020-12-09" => null,
       "2020-12-10" => null,
       "2020-12-11" => null,
       "2020-12-12" => null,
       "2020-12-13" => null,
       "2020-12-14" => 1,
       "2020-12-15" => null,
       "2020-12-16" => null,
     ],
     "canceled" => [
       "2020-11-16" => null,
       "2020-11-17" => 1,
       "2020-11-18" => null,
       "2020-11-19" => null,
       "2020-11-20" => null,
       "2020-11-21" => null,
       "2020-11-22" => null,
       "2020-11-23" => null,
       "2020-11-24" => null,
       "2020-11-25" => null,
       "2020-11-26" => null,
       "2020-11-27" => null,
       "2020-11-28" => null,
       "2020-11-29" => null,
       "2020-11-30" => null,
       "2020-12-01" => null,
       "2020-12-02" => null,
       "2020-12-03" => null,
       "2020-12-04" => null,
       "2020-12-05" => null,
       "2020-12-06" => null,
       "2020-12-07" => null,
       "2020-12-08" => null,
       "2020-12-09" => null,
       "2020-12-10" => null,
       "2020-12-11" => null,
       "2020-12-12" => null,
       "2020-12-13" => null,
       "2020-12-14" => null,
       "2020-12-15" => null,
       "2020-12-16" => null,
     ],
     "no_show" => [
       "2020-11-16" => null,
       "2020-11-17" => null,
       "2020-11-18" => null,
       "2020-11-19" => null,
       "2020-11-20" => null,
       "2020-11-21" => null,
       "2020-11-22" => null,
       "2020-11-23" => null,
       "2020-11-24" => null,
       "2020-11-25" => null,
       "2020-11-26" => null,
       "2020-11-27" => null,
       "2020-11-28" => null,
       "2020-11-29" => null,
       "2020-11-30" => null,
       "2020-12-01" => null,
       "2020-12-02" => null,
       "2020-12-03" => null,
       "2020-12-04" => null,
       "2020-12-05" => null,
       "2020-12-06" => null,
       "2020-12-07" => null,
       "2020-12-08" => null,
       "2020-12-09" => null,
       "2020-12-10" => null,
       "2020-12-11" => null,
       "2020-12-12" => null,
       "2020-12-13" => null,
       "2020-12-14" => 1,
       "2020-12-15" => null,
       "2020-12-16" => null,
     ],
   ]
```

**Further**

Now my next challenge is to remove **sparse data** such as date (x axis) and null (y-axis) if there is null in all the groups/segments (confirm, cancel,no show), just to ensure final graph is clean. For example, if there is null for all 3 groups on the same date, it doesn't need to be there.

Answer (score 2):

Not in Eloquent cause you can't add data from nothing.

But you can use CarbonPeriod, something like this:

```
$ranges = CarbonPeriod::create($start_date, '1 day', $end_date);
```

You can iterate through $ranges and manipulate/merge your data

[Example here](https://implode.io/8ibXn1)